# Error on free char** table

Tags: c, arrays, char, free

I have a function that takes a string and split it into tokens, because I want to return these tokens I allocate a variable using malloc.

```
char** analyze(char* buffer)
{
  int i= 0;
  char* token[512];

  char** final = (char**)malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);
  if ( final == NULL ) { perror("Failed to malloc"); exit(10); }

  token[i] = strtok(buffer, " ");
  while( token[i] != NULL )
  {
    final[i] = malloc(strlen(token[i])+1);
    if( final[i] == NULL ) { perror("Failed to malloc"); exit(11); }

    final[i] = token[i];

    i++;
    token[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
   }

   final[i] = malloc(sizeof(char));
   if( final[i] == NULL ) { perror("Failed to malloc"); exit(12); }
   final[i] = NULL;

   return final;
}
```

And I try to free this table with another function:

```
void free_table(char** job)
{
  int i = 0;

  while( job[i] != NULL )
  {
    free(job[i]);
    i++;
  }
  free(job[i]); //free the last 
  free(job);
}
```

In main I use:

```
char** job = analyze(buffer); // buffer contains the string
```

and

```
free_table(job);
```

when I try to free the table I get this error:

```
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007ffd003f62b0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7fdb2e5497e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7fe0a)[0x7fdb2e551e0a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7fdb2e55598c]
./a.out[0x4012d6]
```

and the error goes on...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `free the list` thing makes no sense. You broke out of the `while` loop, so you know for sure that `job[i]` is `NULL`. So `free(job[i])` absolutely, definitely does nothing.

Comment: I'm also quite puzzled why, at the end of `analyze`, you allocate some memory for `final[i]`, check that it's not NULL, and then set `final[i]` to NULL. What was the point of allocating memory and ensuring you got it just to set `final[i]` to NULL and not use that memory for anything?

Comment: Because i dont know how many tokens will the string have, i just thought that one way to printf all the tokens is in a loop that will stop when the token becomes equal to NULL. Just like the way we use strtok. So i allocate the last posistion of the table and give it the value of NULL so i can return it. Is ti wrong do it that way? I dont know if i must allocate final[i] to just pass NULL to it. I just think this is the correct way because i have to allocate all the table right?

Comment: What does "allocate the last position of the table" mean? Do you mean to make sure the table is big enough to have enough positions? If so, you should be allocating a large table, not one entry.

Comment: I am noob in C..cause of that i wanted to allocate all the positions of the table to return it. But i want the last position to be null (because i want to have this loop). So i thought that i have to allocate this position too...but i think this not necessary, right? @David Schwartz

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "allocate this position". A table is a bunch of positions. If you allocate a big enough table, you've allocated every position in it. The question is what will go in that position. If it's a pointer to something, you'll have to allocate that something. But if it's `NULL`, what else would you need to allocate? The position already exists, since the table is a collection of positions.

Comment: Oh ok! Thank you, i just didnt know that the postion will exist thats why i allocated it. When i did malloc(strlen(buffer)); i thought that i allocate a table that can hold all the string. For instance, if the buffer is (Hello from here) i thought that i allocate 3 posisitions that each one points to another that i need to allocate strlen(Hello); strlen(from); strlen(here) seperately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with:

```
char** final = (char**)malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);
```

This allocates `strlen(buffer) + 1` ***bytes***, not that amount of "elements". And since `sizeof(char*)` is most likely very much larger than a single byte, you might be allocating to little memory here.

Since you don't know how many tokens there might be you should not allocate a fixed amount, but instead use [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) to reallocate as needed.

Then the second problem:

```
final[i] = malloc(strlen(token[i])+1);
...
final[i] = token[i];
```

In the first statement you allocate memory enough for the string pointed to by `token[i]`, and assign the pointer to that memory to `final[i]`. ***But*** then you immediately *reassign* `final[i]` to point somewhere else, some memory that you haven't gotten from `malloc`. You should [*copy* the string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) instead of reassigning the pointer:

```
strcpy(final[i], token[i]);
```

---

On an unrelated note, there's no need for `token` to be an array of pointer. It can be just a pointer:

```
char *token = strtok(...);
```

---

Example of a possible implementation:

```
char **analyze(char *buffer)
{
    size_t current_token_index = 0;
    char **tokens = NULL;

    // Get the first "token"
    char *current_token = strtok(buffer, " ");

    while (current_token != NULL)
    {
        // (Re)allocate memory for the tokens array
        char **temp = realloc(tokens, sizeof *temp * (current_token_index + 1));
        if (temp == NULL)
        {
            // TODO: Better error handling
            //       (like freeing the tokens already allocated)
            return NULL;
        }

        tokens = temp;

        // Allocate memory for the "token" and copy it
        tokens[current_token_index++] = strdup(current_token);

        // Get the next "token"
        current_token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    // Final reallocation to make sure there is a terminating null pointer
    char **temp = realloc(tokens, sizeof *temp * (current_token_index + 1));
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        // TODO: Better error handling
        //       (like freeing the tokens already allocated)
        return NULL;
    }

    tokens = temp;

    // Terminate the array
    tokens[current_token_index] = NULL;

    return tokens;
}
```

Note that `strdup` isn't a standard C function, but it is prevalent enough to assume it will exist. In the unlikely case where it doesn't exist, it's easy to implement yourself.

Comment: Ok i have some questions here, i would apreciate it if you can answer. First of all the malloc(strlen(buffer)+1) is wrong? I just thought that this was the way to allocate the memory that you strictly need. Should i use malloc(sizeof(char*)*strlen(buffer)+1)? Is this the correct way? Also, the correct way to malloc a char** is like the function i present, right?

Comment: @P3ett Close, you need parentheses around the addition. ***However***, while you may know how many *characters* there is in the input string, you don't know how many *tokens* there are. That's why I recommended using `realloc` to reallocate the array as needed.

Comment: I dont know how many tokens will my string has, but with the loop that stops when token[i] equals to NULL its like i know, right? I mean, i will not allocate extra space because my loop will break when i have the tokens that actually exists in the string.

Comment: @P3ett What if the string is e.g. `"foo bar"`. That's two space-delimited tokens, right? But it's seven characters. So once you fix the `malloc` call you will allocate an array of eight `char*` (effectively) but you only need three.

Comment: So what is the correct way to malloc a char** table? I thought that the first one must be allocated to take all the buffer (thats why i put strlen(buffer)) and then malloc its tokens seperatly. Should a char** final = malloc(sizeof(char*)) be enough? I try this on my code and it worked but i dont know if this is right or wrong

Comment: @P3ett Added a possible implementation of your function that allocates just enough elements.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean. Can you present me some code of allocaion of a char** table with strlen to see what is the correct way? I have searched for this in the internet but i never find an allocation with strlen.

Comment: @P3ett But I'm telling you that using `strlen(buffer)` to allocate the `tokens` (or `final`) arrays is *wrong!* It will allocate to much memory that will be wasted and unused. ***Why*** do you want to waste memory?